# @WebFluxTest throws org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder has not been registered error on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gcp

I've built a Spring WebFlux application (Annotated Controller model) that integrates with Google Cloud Services with the below mentioned library versions. I've written a test for Controller class and when it is run on my local machine it runs without any issue. But when the same test is run on Jenkins pipeline it throws **Binder has not been registered** error.

*Spring Boot Version      - 2.5.5

Spring Cloud GCP Version  - 2.0.4*

The error that gets printed on the Jenkins console is as below

```
[ERROR] com.test.controller.ControllerTest.shouldPostRequestToEndpoint  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder has not been registered
```

The most confusing thing is this **issue happens only on Jenkins instance and not on my local machine** and it makes it very difficult to debug. I'm not sure on why it appears that way. Also, not sure how to register any Binder here. If I could get any help/direction on where the issue might be or how to debug, it would be very helpful.

Sample Controller and ControllerTest class can be found below.

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Mono<String> test() {
        return service.test(LocalDateTime.now())
                .then(Mono.just("SUCCESS"));
    }
}
```

**ControllerTest.java**

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    Service service;
    
    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void shouldPostRequestToEndpoint() {
        given(service.test(any(LocalDateTime.class))).willReturn(empty());
        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/test")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(String.class);
    }
}
```

Even if you guys point me towards identifying what Binder needs to be registered, it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like spring context can't load. Is your JUnit version different between local and CI? If you use JUnit4, try adding `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to your test.

Comment: I use JUnit5 and @WebFluxTest already has @ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class}) annotated to it. Could you suggest me something for JUnit5?

Comment: Troubleshooting here would have to start with Spring application context loading. Look at the output from Jenkins and compare it to the local output -- look for differences in the Spring context loading.

Comment: Identified the issue when commented the main class test. It was an issue with main class test that triggered failure for all other tests that involves application context load.